# Bash howto write/read to/from a named pipe without aborting after first sending

Tags: bash, pipe, mkfifo

**GIVEN:**

Bash command line (Terminal 1):

```
 > mkfifo pipo
 > cat pipo
```

Bash command line (Terminal 2):

```
 > echo -e "Hello World\nHi" > pipo
```

**RESULT:**

The bash in (Terminal 1) prints:

```
 Hello World
 Hi
```

and aborts.

**QUESTION:**

How can I achieve that it does not abort, but allows to send another echo through `pipo`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `echo ... > fifo` opens and then closes the fifo. As a workaround you can do like this:

```
# open for writing
exec 20> fifo
echo foo >&20
echo bar >&20
...
# to close it
exec 20>&-
```

A bit explanation:

- `exec 20> fifo` opens `fifo` for *writing* with FD (file descriptor) 20.
- `command >&20` redirects the output to FD 20.
- `exec 20>&-` closes FD 20.

---

The following are excerpts from `man bash`:

> - exec [-cl] [-a *name*] [*command* [*arguments*]]
>
>   [...] **If** *command* **is not  specified,  any redirections  take effect** in the current shell, and the return status is 0.  If there is a redirection error, the return status is 1.
> - [*n*]>*word*
>
>   Redirection  of output causes the file whose name results from the expansion of ***word*** to be opened for **writing** on **file descriptor *n***, or the standard output (file descriptor 1) if ***n*** is not  specified.   If the file does not exist it is created; if it does exist it is truncated to zero size. [...]
> - [*n*]>&*word*
>
>   [...] If ***word*** evaluates to `-`, file descriptor ***n*** is closed. [...]

Comment: Would you, please, elaborate on the solution? What does ``exec 20> fifo`` do, for example?

Comment: updated the answer. there's quite a lot about this. `man bash` for [detailed doc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html).

Comment: Does file descriptor 20 have a special meaning?

Comment: 20 is not special. usually the shell only uses 0 (stdin), 1 (stdout) and 2 (stderr).

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal 1 do

```
tail -f pipo
```

instead of `cat pipo`.